# Get password silently from clipboard in Python

Tags: python, passwords, getpass

The standard way to enter a password in Python without echoing it is using getpass.getpass().

However,it doesn't support clipboard input (ctrl-V), which is needed when dealing with complex, highly secure passwords.

Has anyone ever come up with a workaround (get the password silently from crtl-V)?

Thanks!

R.

Comment: For text applications the clipboard is a matter of the terminal program.

Comment: Indeed, but input() does accept clipboard input.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to right click paste from clipboard into the command prompt as an alternative.

Unfortunately `getpass.getpass()` uses `getwch()` from Windows C, which does not allow `CTRL+C` to be read.